# Storing a large vector as a const in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a text file with approx. 10 million numbers that I'd like to store as a const vector in my C++ program.

The hope is to speed up some operations by using compile time optimization.

Several questions:

Is this a good idea?

If so, what is the best way to do it?  Format the text file into a header file?

Comment: Don't expect to see performance improvements to your code based on accessing the vector. You'll have to find other places to get performance gains.

Comment: The "cleanest" way to do would be to declare an `extern` pointer, and use the linker to embed the data in its own section. But your gains would be essentially the same as if you `mmap`ed the file, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: A little caveat, this "could" actually make sense (and is standard practice to some degree) if the executable would be loaded directly from high-latency, high-throughput storage (like in a DVD-based game console). But I suspect you are not making a PS2 game here.

Comment: How exactly does your text file look like? You could eventually generate a header file from it easily. Though as others mentioned I also have thorough doubts that you'll gain very much performance in actually processing that data.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking I could craft a header file and extern the variable.  The text file is currently one line per number.  For the sake of an example, let's say I have a function that compares my constant vector A to parameter B vector element wise in a for loop, e.g.: `if(A[j] < B[j]) sum += A[j]*B[j];`.  Would I see any speed up in this example?

Comment: To optimize the performance, you have to ensure that your algorithm that works on data is efficient... You have to profile to know which operations are slower. Cache pattern can have an impact on performance...

Comment: @thc if `j` is known at compile-time, then yes, the compiler would be able to do some magic, but this is rarely the case for datasets this large.

Comment: Thanks @Frank.  `j` would be in a for loop from `0` to `B.size() - 1`.  I think I'll try out the extern/header approach and see if it makes a difference.